# VS Code (JavaScript) warn if import path is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been a WebStorm user for a long time and have just shifted to VS Code. One of the WebStorm features I like that I can't seem to find in VS Code is the ability to warn me if an import path is wrong. For example:

```js
import { MyModule } from '../MyModulee';
```

Assuming the directory name is really `MyModule` WebStorm would warn me that the path could not be found. Is there a comparable extension for VS Code to do this?

Comment: It should do that without the need for any extension. [VS Code JavaScript Support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)

Comment: It definitely does not for me. It's not until I hit runtime exceptions that I realize there is a typo. I'm using the stock VS Code (just installed) and loaded up the following extensions: eslint, intellisense, path intellisense, and prettier. Would any of those make that functionality go away?

Comment: I just tested this with only two js files and nothing else, and I do get an error if I try to import something that does not exist. Check in settings for "JavaScript Validate" and turn that on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that was on, but what did it for me was: JavaScript > Implicit Project Config: Check JS. Turning that on then gives me the red underline on bad imports. Thanks!