# (Kiwi Browser) (Chromium 120) (Chrome Extension MV3) — Service Worker Registration Failed & Syntax Error Due to Import Statement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need a help regarding my chrome extension that I'm developing.

I am using: **Kiwi Browser**, It's version is **Chromium 120**. I am also using manifest v3 aswell.

Let's get right into the issue.

#### My extension directory structure:

Project (main directory)

- manifest.json

  - scripts (folder)

    - background.js ( The script, to which I want to import )
    - content.js ( unrelated )
    - rosafeutility.js ( The script, from which I want to import. )
- css (folder)
- resource (folder)

#### Entire code (with each file merged into one single code for you to understand.)

```
// manifest.json
// NOTE: Some parts are HIDDEN to make the json simpler for you to see. Some parts are UNRELATED.

{

  "manifest_version": 3,

  "name": "RoSafe",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "background": {

    "service_worker": "background.js",

    "type": "module"

  }

}

// background.js

try {

  import * as RoSafeUtility from './scripts/rosafeutility.js'

} catch (e) {

  console.log(e);

}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addEventListener((info) => {

  if (info.reason === "install") {

    console.log("test");

  }

});

// rosafeutility.js

export const RoSafeStorage = {

  trySetData: function(data) {

    return new Promise((success, fail) => {

      return chrome.storage.local.set(data).then(() => {

        return { success: "true" };

      });

    }

  })

}

export class RosafeLocalData {

  constructor(data) {

    this.isNewUser = data.isNewUser;

    this.settings = data.settings;

  }

}
```

#### The desired imported file (rosafeutility.js)

```
export const RoSafeStorage =
{
  trySetData: function(data) {
    return new Promise((success, fail) =>
    {
      return chrome.storage.local.set(data).then(() =>
      {
        return { success: "true"};
      });
    });
  }
};
  
export class RosafeLocalData
{
  constructor(data)
  {
    this.isNewUser = data.isNewUser;
    this.settings = data.settings;
  }
}
```

#### The problem:

- Adding the line (import statement) in wrapped try & catch statement actually causes the issue.
- Without it, there is no issue and the extension can run fine but I want to import scripts.

#### What I have tried:

- Using importScripts(), this caused the error (`DOMException: Failed to import 'chrome-extension://licillijhmbamnlcikgdanflicecmoip/scripts/scripts/rosafeutility.js'. importScripts() of new scripts after service worker installation is not allowed.`).
- Trying multiple ways of using import statements, including export.
- Moving all scripts to the root directory of the project. Still causes the issue.
- Debugging the extension to attempt to find issue, but the only generic error shown is (`Service Worker Registration Failed.`).

#### Some answers you may have:

- **Upgrade the browser to latest version**

  - It is already the latest.
- **Try different browser**

  - I tried it, even multiple browsers, but it does not work, All same issue.
- **Ask ChatGPT**

  - You serious bro?

Comment: `import` statements have to appear at the outermost code context in a module. They cannot be inside any `{ }` blocks.

Comment: Also, when asking about an error message of any sort, it's important to include in your question the **exact** message you get from the browser (or Node or whatever).

Comment: why is your code double spaced?

Comment: perhaps you want to use the dynamic `import` instead?

Comment: - My code might be double spaced because the stackoverflow sucks at formating lol, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Is the dynamic import not supported?

Comment: @Pointy My code (import statement) in background.js is in the outermost code context, it is not any block, function, class, etc. Plus even if I remove try & catch statement, it still doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Mubinet no, being in a `try` block is not the same. It has to be absolutely at the outermost level of nesting, with no `{ }`. Global to the module, in other words.

Comment: A `try` block is not going to do anything useful anyway.

Comment: Dynamic import is not supported in service workers. As explained above the static `import` should be used without `try`. If "it still doesn't work anyway" for you it means there's a different problem in the imported file, which you need to debug in devtools. You won't be able to do it if the error occurs during the import because ManifestV3 is retarded. There are some complicated workarounds which are hard to describe in short, so it'd be easier if you just show the entire `rosafeutility.js`.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. Well, I am bit confused because I removed the try block, the `import` is already located in first line and is at the most outermost level. (Meaning there is no `{  }` containing import statement). I even removed the entire code in ` background.js ` and only included `import` statement, but it still causes the same error.

Comment: The error message is the same because ManifestV3 is poorly implemented and doesn't show the real error, which is now caused by something inside the imported code. Can you show your rosafeutility.js? The most common mistake is to use DOM and other `window`-specific globals.

Comment: I edited the question as to show rosafeutility.js. That's entire code.

Comment: There's a syntax error: `)` is placed incorrectly in the first block. Use an IDE/editor that checks JS.

Comment: @wOxxOm Used VSCode + javascript vaildator, I fixed some syntax errors like you mentioned. Tried running the extension with updated code, the errors `Service Worker Registration` and `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.` only showed up. I'll edit the question to include the updated code.

Comment: Remove `/scripts` from import statement because the imported file is in the same folder as the current script ie. it should be './rosafeutility.js';

Comment: See also comments in [VS Code (JavaScript) warn if import path is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62921684)

Comment: I removed /scripts from `import` statement and changed the method from `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addEventListener` to `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` and... DAMN it worked, thank you so much. How can I mark your comment as solution?